# Regex a 13 digit number in the middle of a URL

Tags: regex, web-scraping

I am using Kimono Labs to scrape a bunch of websites. I'd like to extract individual IDs from URLs that HTML attributes that I generate using Kimono. Kimono allows regex only in this format -

```
/^()(.*?)()$/
```

I have a bunch of URLs in this representative format -

```
http://www.abcde.com/inferno-english/p/itmdzhspdfkfszyk?pid=9780593072493&srno=b_3&ref=e32b55b4-b0b0-413d-b76c-a41ad93247a5
```

What Regex do i use to extract the 13 digit number after the "pid=" ?

Comment: `\d` for digit and `{}` for amount: `pid=\d{13}` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
pid=(\d{13})
```

You can use this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dM0rS8/1

Comment: Thanks -- but Kimono is throwing up a blank result for this. (This is what I had tried initially too). I am not sure if it has to do with the exact format kimono specifies for the regex. They say the content generated by the middle bracket is what is finally taken. Pls see this -- http://vimeo.com/98827385

Comment: @melony middle bracket means?

Comment: there are three pairs of brackets in the prescribed format -- refer to the second pair

Comment: @melony the brackets seem correct. try `pid=([0-9]{13})

Answer (score 0):

Group index 1 contains the 13 digit number which was present just after to pid=,

```
/^.*?pid=(\d+).*$/
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bA0jG5/2)

**OR**

To get the exact 13 digits,

```
/^.*?pid=(\d{13}).*$/
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bA0jG5/3)

Comment: Why a downvote? OP means the 13 digit only in the example itself.

Answer (score 0):

use positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=pid=)\d{13}
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/bA0jG5/1

Answer (score 0):

Kimono syntax requires using the 3 sets of parentheses, so you would need to do something like:

```
 /(pid=)(\d{13})()/
```

You can also just contact support and they will create the regex for you.